# Ошибка The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: java, html, jquery, tomcat

Подскажите какими способами можно решить данную проблему. Столкнулся с лимитом более 65535 байт.
Ошибка 
**The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit**

Файл jsp
Использую Tomcat 7

**Поделюсь проблемой подробнее**

Список данных moList берется с mo.txt

```
<form:label path="moId"><spring:message code="label.mo" /</form:label>
<form:select path="moId">
<form:option value="0" label=" " />
<form:options items="${moList}"/>
</form:select>
```

Но мне необходимо сделать свою сортировку. Т.е. в каком положении я указал список – в таком и будет показываться в программе.

```
<form:label path="moId"><spring:message code="label.mo" /></form:label>
<form:select path="moId">
<form:option value="0" label="" />
<form:option value="1" label="0001 МН" />
<form:option value="2" label="0002 КД" />
<form:option value="3" label="0004 РЗ" />
. . .
</form:select>
```

Таких  у меня много строк, тем самым если я их все ввожу в jsp файл, то выбрасывает ошибку **The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit**
Можно ли сделать типа ссылку на отдельный файл … Пожалуйста предложите варианты как можно решить эту проблему. Пробовал сокращать код но безрезультатно, все равно превышает  65535.

Comment: У вас реально выпадающий список размером 64 килобайта? Чтобы его проскролить нужно не меньше получаса?

Comment: В списке у меня 260 строк и он выпадает в проекте сразу. Есть в данном файле jsp не только данный список но и другой код.

Comment: jsp-страница - это шаблон презентационного слоя, если он получается большой, то вы неправильно его используете. Кода в нём вообще быть не должно, кроме декларативного минимума, а объёмный текст стоит подгружать из базы или бандлов.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Но нужная сортировка у меня пока только таким вариантом получается.

Comment: 260 строк никак не могут занимать 64 килобайта. Ну, если у вас в каждой строке не "Война и мир". Ищите проблему в других частях шаблона.

Comment: Без данного выпадающего списка файл jsp весит 89Kb и все работает, но когда  вместе строчки <form:options items="${moList}"/> вставляю желаемый список такого рода <form:option value="1" label="0001 МН" /> - Выкидывает ошибку. Кстати, весит этот список без остального кода 20Kb. Превышение похоже и без желаемого списка, но и проект не выдает ошибку с 89Kb.

Comment: У вас слишком большой jsp-файл и список становится последней каплей. Уменьшайте.

Comment: Удвоить jsp-файл можно?

Comment: Лимит в 64k? Нет, это фундаментальное ограничение JVM.